# cURL connection drops despite being set to indefinate

Tags: php, curl, connection

We wrote a php/ajax application that connects to an API through cURL.  We built it to stay connected indefinately, it worked fine, we were happy, used it periodically, then moved on to other projects.

We re-visited it recently and discovered that it had begun timing out at varying intervals.  We checked the script looking for anything that could affect the cURL calls.  Nothing.

We had, and have, these options in our simple cURL script:

```
$sch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $sch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_URL, $test_url);
curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'get_data');
curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
$output = curl_exec($sch);
```

My understanding is that the effect of the NOSIGNAL and TIMEOUT options is what kept our connection open.

But it's not working.

I have two questions.
1) any ideas on the coding, anything we're missing in the cURL, or could there be something elsewhere in the code that could affect the connection?  What could affect the connection?
2) if the problem is not with the coding, how can we check the upstream connection. How do you detect where, and why, the connection is actually being dropped?

Thank you for your suggestions and if you have any questions or need other information, don't hesitate to post.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` as well:

```
curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
```

Also, try adding

```
if (curl_errno($sch) > 0) {
    error_log(sprintf(
        "Curl error %d: %s for %s\n", 
        curl_errno($sch), 
        curl_error($sch), 
        $test_url
    ));
}
```

to see what, exactly, is failing.

Comment: Thanks Ross - we didn't have the connecttimeout in the script because there was no problem connecting. The problem is staying connected.  I did insert it into our script, though, and it still drops the connection after 30-120 seconds.  We also have scripting in place to check the curl_error.  We appreciate your answer.

Comment: Is it occurring on all urls, or only certain urls? What is CURL's exact error message?

Comment: You've inadvertently pointed us in the right direction, we no longer believe there is a failure with cURL.  While trying to print the curl_errors, I commented out 'curl_setopt($sch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'get_data');' to keep it from running upon the execution of curl_exec.  CURL connected and stayed connected as it should.    We blamed cURL too soon, we were wrong.  Thank you for you help Ross, sorry for my not performing due diligence on this matter.